# How can I link rpmdb library with makefile?

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, nautilus

I try to install nautilus-rpm in Fedora 15.

This is error message.

```
[test@localhost nautilus-rpm-0.1]$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/designmade/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/designmade/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1/src'
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall   -o librpmdb-method.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/modules -module -avoid-version rpmdb.lo -pthread -lgnomevfs-2 -lgconf-2 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lrpm -lrpmdb -lrpmio -lpopt 
rm -fr .libs/librpmdb-method.la .libs/librpmdb-method.* .libs/librpmdb-method.*
gcc -shared  rpmdb.lo  -lgnomevfs-2 -lgconf-2 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lrpm -lrpmdb -lrpmio -lpopt  -Wl,-soname -Wl,librpmdb-method.so -o .libs/librpmdb-method.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrpmdb
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [librpmdb-method.la] 오류 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/designmade/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] 오류 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/designmade/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1'
make: *** [all] 오류 2
```

and I try to find files about rpmdb.

```
[root@localhost nautilus-rpm-0.1]# find / -name *rpmdb*
/var/lib/yum/rpmdb-indexes
/usr/bin/rpmdb
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_load
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_verify
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_loadcvt
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_recover
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_dump
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_stat
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_upgrade
/usr/include/rpm/rpmdb.h
/usr/share/man/man8/rpmdb.8.gz
/home/test/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1/src/.deps/rpmdb.Plo
/home/test/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1/src/rpmdb.desktop.in
/home/test/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1/src/rpmdb.lo
/home/test/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1/src/rpmdb.o
/home/test/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1/src/rpmdb.conf
/home/designmade/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1/src/rpmdb.c
/home/designmade/다운로드/nautilus-rpm-0.1/src/rpmdb.keys.in
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`librpmdb` merged with `librpm` in 4.6:

http://community.ingres.com/forum/database-general/2467-gui-installer-wont-work-fedora-core-10-a.html

So use `-lrpm` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need a development package containing librpmdb.so.

Comment: Which development package would that be?

Comment: Looks like that API is obsolete as it last appeared in Fedora 9 [`rpm-libs`](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/librpmdb-4.4.so)